# How to copy list values during debugging?

Tags: kotlin, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm new to Kotlin - during debugging when I try to copy "points" list by `right click> submenu> Copy Value`

[image]

in clipboard, instead of all points data, I get

> size = 12

How to copy all list values during debuggin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy list values, first choose `View as> toString`

[image]

and then when you copy value like in question, you will get all list values

> [Point(x=1123.144274001786, y=1084.118525837639, value=null), Point(x=1123.144274854474, y=1931.868690835885, value=null), Point(x=1127.144273590326, y=1931.868690835872, value=null), Point(x=1127.144400516677, y=1893.118527129657, value=null), ... ]